# GIT ubuntu 12.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, git

I was wondering if anyone has installed git and gitosis on ubuntu 12.04 if not what is the best version to go for on the new version of ubuntu?

Any recommendations on the best way to set up GIT are also welcome?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! [SF] **is not a forum**. Please see the [FAQ]. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

According to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/126112/1371) on our sister site askubuntu.com, gitosis is no longer available in the repositories.

Gitolite however is.